# repeating variable issue in windows batch file

Tags: math, windows-7, batch-file, cmd

I have the following code in a batch file:

```
    set /p user="Enter username: " %=%
    cd w:\Files
    @echo off 
    setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
    set /a value=0 
    set /a sum=0 
    set /a valA=0
    FOR /R %1 %%I IN (*) DO ( 
    set /a value=%%~zI/1024 
    set /a sum=!sum!+!value! 
    set /a sum=!sum!/1024
    ) 
    @echo Size of "FILES" is: !sum! MB
    @echo off
    FOR /R %1 %%I IN (*) DO ( 
    set /a sum=!sum!/1024
    set /a valA=!sum!
    )
    @echo Size of "FILES" is: !sum! GB


    cd W:\Documents and Settings\%user%\Desktop
    @echo off 
    setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
    set /a value=0 
    set /a sum=0 
    set /a valB=0
    FOR /R %1 %%I IN (*) DO ( 
    set /a value=%%~zI/1024 
    set /a sum=!sum!+!value! 
    set /a sum=!sum!/1024
    ) 
    @echo Size of Desktop is: !sum! MB
    @echo off
    FOR /R %1 %%I IN (*) DO ( 
    set /a sum=!sum!/1024
    set /a valB=!sum!
    )
    @echo Size of Desktop is: !sum! GB
```

There are a few other folders it checks, but you should get the idea.

I get this output:

```
C:\Users\pprescott\Desktop>cd w:\Files
Size of "FILES" is: 215 MB
Size of "FILES" is: 0 GB
Size of Desktop is: 215 MB
Size of Desktop is: 0 GB
Size of Favorites is: 215 MB
Size of Favorites is: 0 GB
Size of Documents is: 215 MB
Size of Documents is: 0 GB
Total size is: 0 MB
Total size is: 0 GB
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This is designed to count folder size on an old xp machine to prepare for a data transfer. The xp machine is mapped to drive W.

Comment: so what is the issue/question?

Comment: I guess I am seeking some help. If you notice in the output, it repeats the results of the first section of the batch file.

Comment: Please show the command line you use to call the batch.

Comment: the batch is just clicked within windows explorer

Comment: Please show the properties of the shortcut (command line etc).

Comment: http://snag.gy/6MLQN.jpg

Comment: Code enhanced, works here.

Answer (score 2):

try to remove the `for /r` parameter `%1`:

```
FOR /R %%I IN (*) DO (
```

---

Try this code:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
FOR /R "w:\Files" %%I IN (*) DO set /a asum+=%%~zI
SET /a sum=asum/1048576
echo Size of "FILES" is: %sum% MB
set /a sum=asum/1073741824
echo Size of "FILES" is: %sum% GB
FOR /R "W:\Documents and Settings\%user%\Desktop" %%I IN (*) DO set /a asum+=%%~zI
SET /a sum=asum/1048576
echo Size of "DESKTOP" is: %sum% MB
set /a sum=asum/1073741824
echo Size of "DESKTOP" is: %sum% GB
```

Comment: That does not seem to have changed anything. I'll be honest I copy and pasted a lot of this, so I'm not sure what some parts do.

Comment: @endoro remember the limit of 31 bits - what happens when the total size exceeds 2Gb?

Comment: Invalid number.  Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision.
Size of "FILES" is: -1990 MB
Size of "FILES" is: -1 GB
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: when the total size exceeds 2Gb you should skip to Linux :), there is _nothing_ you can do in batch. Use `VBS` or `Powershell`.

Comment: These folders can easily contain up to 60 GB. I was afraid I'd have to go with something else. :/ I am not that familiar with powershell or vb. Can someone help me out?

Comment: count in different units will only work if _every_ file size is lower than 2GB

Answer (score 1):

Use the `dir` command output.  See this example

This will take the folder size and convert it into the different values.
Note that the conversion only works for numeric values up to 2 gigabytes.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=3" %%A IN ('dir /s /-c ^| find /i "bytes" ^| find /v /i "free"') do set T=%%A

echo Bytes = %T%
set /a T/=1024
echo Kilobytes = %T%
set /a T/=1024
echo Megabytes = %T%
set /a T/=1024
echo Gigabytes = %T%
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop>Test.bat
Bytes = 18280552
Kilobytes = 17852
Megabytes = 17
Gigabytes = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This should report the size of the trees in bytes up to 999 GB.

The lower answer uses a VBS script to convert the numbers to GB (dropping decimals)

```
@echo off
call :size "w:\Files"
call :size "W:\Documents and Settings\%user%\Desktop" 
pause
goto :eof
:size
for /f "tokens=3" %%b in ('dir /s "%~1" 2^>nul ^|find " File(s) "') do set "n=%%b"
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%c in ("%n%") do (
echo %%c%%d%%e%%f "%~1"
)
)
```

Solution to return approx GB figures

```
@echo off
call :size "w:\Files"
call :size "W:\Documents and Settings\%user%\Desktop" 
pause
goto :eof
:size
for /f "tokens=3" %%b in ('dir /s "%~1" 2^>nul ^|find " File(s) "') do set "n=%%b"
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%c in ("%n%") do (

>"%temp%\VBS.vbs" echo Set fso = CreateObject^("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^) : Wscript.echo ^(%%c%%d%%e%%f/1024/1024^)
for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%z in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\VBS.vbs"') do echo %%z GB "%~1"
del "%temp%\VBS.vbs"

)
)
```